# Adobe Muse - How to make an object moving across the screen?

Tags: dynamic, adobe, muse

How can i in adobe muse make an object/picture/text move across the screen based on different statements. For example

when page load, move object A from y/x to y/x on page.
or when user clicks on object B change size on object A from h/w to h/w.
or when user dag object A over object B change object C color from green to black.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This effect in Muse is called parallax scrolling.  There is actually a site where you can download a fully operational Muse file that uses parallax scrolling.  Google this and see if you can find that file.  If you do, there should be a tutorial on how to do this as well.

Good luck.